# matlab error :Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

I am trying to run the given code below

```
w = fft(y);
a1 = abs(w);
a2= a1(0:length(w)/2-1);
g = (0:(length(w)/2)-1)*fs/length(w);
figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(g,a2);
title('FFT of X(k): Original signal');
xlabel('frequency(hz)');
ylabel('amplitude of frequency');
```

at the

```
a2 = a1(0:length(w)/2-1);
```

matlab shows an error

> "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: This kind of sucks - I wish I could do something about that.

Answer (score 1):

Index should one-based, so it should be 1:length(w)/2 and not 0:length(w)/2-1